# Maintaining state and messages in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So, I am making a Chrome extension that connects to an external server and allows you to chat with other users of the extension. However, the way my extension is set up right now is with a start page (the initial popup), and then a button that takes you to the chatting page.

I want to figure out a way that allows the extension to stay on the chatting page after the user passed through the start page already. Moreover, I want the chat's messages to be saved as well.

I know I can do this by using `Chrome.pageAction.setPopup()`. However, I don't if this is the way to go about. As for the messages, I am not sure where to start, do I store them in Chrome localStorage? what are the ways I can go about doing this?

I apologize if this is a trivial question, I am new to all this.

Comment: Is the chatting page an extension page or a external web page or the page on popup?

Comment: It is a page on a popup, however, I have found a solution and will post the answer tomorrow.